# OBJ File: Why are there so many normal indices in comparison to normal values?

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d, wavefront

So I am reading obj files and make lists to store the vertices, texture vertices, normal, vertex texture and normal indices. Testing this with a cube results in 8 vertices and 6 normals but there are 24 items in the normal indices list.

Can anyone explain why this is as I am a little confused right now?

Comment: Any given normal value can be referenced by multiple faces.

Comment: There are 24 indices because you need 24 distinct vertices to describe a cube with per-face normals.

Answer (score 2):

The OBJ format is designed for Gouraud shading, with one normal per vertex; rather than flat shading, one normal per polygon. Pick a cube face, go through the file data and write down the normal indices and normals. You'll see why.

Comment: Pretty sure vertices and normals are not (necessarily) one-to-one; each vertex can correspond to up to the same number of normals as the number of faces which share it